# How to pass integer as parameter in POST request in Volley?

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I tried the following function to pass key as a `String` and value as an `Integer` but it gives an error.

```
@Override
protected Map<String, Integer> getParams() {
    Map<String, Integer> params = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    params.put("id", 12);

    return params;
}
```

Comment: post your error log @suti

Comment: which error you faced .....

Comment: Error:(112, 51) error: getParams()  cannot override getParams() in Request
return type Map<String,Integer> is not compatible with Map<String,String>

Answer (score 0):

better you should use `String.valueOf()` with String parameters like below

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("id", String.valueOf(12));

    return params;
}
```

Comment: but i need an integer value to pass as the POST parameter. Is it possible?

Comment: @shizhen OmiK params.put("id", String.valueof(12));  but not get result please help

Answer (score -1):

Change this to-:

```
params.put("id", 12);
```

To-:

```
params.put("id", String.valueof(12));
```

or

```
params.put("id", "12");
```

Because as you can see it only accepts String values.

Comment: I tried that but the api requires an integer value for a successful hit.